# En el navegador aparece impresa toda la sentencia @if en laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, condiciones, laravel-blade, laravel-6

Tengo la siguiente duda en el código estoy utilizando dos veces la misma lista, la diferencia es que la primera vez necesito aparezcan todos los datos lo cual ya lo tengo pero en su segundo uso solo necesito colocar un if para filtrar un valor que sea id=5.

El problema esta en que al actualizar la página del proyecto de Laravel me sale impresa toda la sentencia y tampoco hace el filtrado.

Espero me puedan ayudar con esta duda. Muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: Imagen con el código afectado]

Comment: Por favor el código como texto, además ¿nos puedes explicar mejor tu duda?

Comment: Remueve los `{{ }}` en tu condicional if, no son necesarios ahí.

Comment: Yo te preguntaría: ¿tus archivos si tiene la extensión .blade? es decir algo como esto: `archivo.blade.php`

Comment: @BetaM , es correcto cuento con el archivo llamado index.blade.php

Comment: @BetaM Lo que sucede es que en el navegador aparece toda la sentencia @ if .... y entiendo que esto no es correcto ya que no busco mostrar el @ if si no el filtrado que hace osea el nombre del usuario donde el id sea igual a 5.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando utilizas variables `php` dentro de tus plantillas debes de saber que para llamarlas en una etiqueta `HTML` basta con usar {{`variable`}} en la etiqueta, tal como este ejemplo:

```
<h1>{{$title}}</h1>
```

Sin embargo, cuando utilizas estructuras de control como `@if @foreach @switch` dentro de las condicionales de las mismas no es necesario utilizar las llaves dobles. Basta simplemente con llamar a tu variable como lo harías en php, por ejemplo:

```
@if($usuario->edad > 18)
<p>{{$usuario->nombre}} es mayor de edad.</p>
@endif
```

Una excepción es cuando utilizas la directiva `@php`, esta te sirve para incluir código PHP en tu plantilla, es parecido a utilizar `<?php  ?>` donde todo dentro de la directiva es código PHP. Un ejemplo sería.

```
@php
$kids = array();
foreach($people as $kid) { 
    if($kid->age < 18)
        array_push($kids, $kid);
}
@endphp
```

De esta manera puedes declarar nuevas funciones o hacer cálculos en tus páginas. Puedes notar que cuando utilizamos las sentencias `if` o `foreach`, no agregamos el `@`. Espero esto te sirva un poco de ayuda.

Otra cosa, en tu código veo que tienes algo como `p.id`, desconozco si es correcto utlizar el punto o debas usar `->` en su lugar. Puedes probarlo.

Comment: Ya realce la modificación a @if($p->id==5), y ahora en el navegador se muestra tal como esta la sentencia, lo que me comentas p.id por lo que he leído del código se genera en angular, este código no lo escribi yo espero puedas entender que puede ser algo complicado.

Comment: Ok, entonces ¿estas utilizando Laravel para el backend y Angular para el frontend, pero tu código es un archivo blade.php?